# "5 minus 4 sind gleich 1". Why plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, mathematics

I have just been watching [a video about "Schriftliches Dividieren"](https://youtu.be/QpP7InGNX98?t=64) and it has occured to me that, when referring to calculations, i.e:

> "5 minus 4 equals/is 1"

the word "is" or "equals" has a plural form, that is

> "5 minus 4 sind gleich 1"

What is the reasoning behind it? 
Is it because "5 minus 4" is treated not as a single calculation but as two numbers? Or because the plural form corresponds to the subject, in this case the number 4 or 5, which are both plural?

Would it sound bad for a native speaker if I used a singular form, that is "5 minus 4 ist gleich 1"? And if so, when is "ist gleich" permitted?

Comment: Es sind mindestens 2 Opernden in der Gleichung, der Plural ist m.E. qualifiziert. Es hat nicht's mit den Zahlen an sich zu tun.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Analoges Gegenbeispiel mit zwei Operanden: Die Gleichung W XOR F = W lautet in Worten "entweder Wahr oder Falsch **ist** Wahr".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich hätte hier

> 5 minus 4 ist gleich 1

gesagt, und ich denke, das ist die gängigere Praxis. Die Logik dahinter ist

> (5 minus 4) ist gleich 1

Jedoch lässt es nach meiner Beobachtung das deutsche Sprachgefühl zur Not auch zu,

> 5 minus 4 sind gleich 1

zu sagen, nämlich wenn man es interpretiert als

> 5 (minus 4) sind gleich 1,

oder anders gesagt:

> 5 (gezählte Dinge) sind gleich 1 (gezähltes Ding), wenn man vorher 4 (gezählte Dinge) davon abzieht.

Kurz: Es kommt darauf an, auf was man das Verb bezogen fühlt, auf nur die 5 oder auf (5 minus 4).

Comment: So, wäre es richtig, wenn ich sage "1 minus 3 **ist** -2"?

Comment: *ist gleich (habe ich mich vertippt).

Comment: @c.p. Ja, *1 - 3 = -2* spricht man in aller Regel aus als *Eins minus drei ist gleich minus zwei*. Oder so war es jedenfalls, als ich zur Schule ging. Wobei man das *ist gleich* eigentlich ausspricht wie *istgleich* mit Betonung auf *ist*. Aber korrekt schreiben würde man es dennoch als *ist gleich*.

Answer (score 10):

Good observation. In fact, the expression 5 - 4 = 1 should be read as

> Fünf minus vier **ist** (gleich) eins.
>
> <sub>Five minus four **is** (equal to) one.</sub>

The equality sign within an expression *A = B* puts the entire left term *A*, here 5 - 4, into an equivalence relation with the entire right term *B*, here 1. No matter how complicated the compositions of *A* and *B* are — whether they contain a single mathematical object such as the number 1 in *B* or multiple mathematical objects such as the numbers 5 and 4 in *A* —, they are single terms. The numerus of the verb *to be*, therefore, should be singular, as well:

> (Term) *A* **ist** (gleich) (Term) *B*.
>
> <sub>(Term) *A* **is** (equal to) (term) *B*.</sub>
>
> Fünf minus drei **ist** zwei.
>
> <sub>Five minus three **is** (equal to) two.</sub>

One could argue that the speaker might have had implicit objects, such as apples (Äpfel), in mind when doing the calculation. And indeed, it would be correct to say

> Fünf Äpfel minus drei Äpfel **sind zwei** Äpfel.
>
> <sub>Five apples minus three apples **are two** apples.</sub>

However, this doesn't work in the original calculation, because its result is a single apple. So, it should be singular anyway:

> Fünf Äpfel minus vier Äpfel **ist ein** Apfel.
>
> <sub>Five apples minus four apples **is one** apple.</sub>

Comment: I can't quite wrap my head around it – should the verb match the subject or the object? Your last sentence implies the latter, but when I come to think about it, I'd say "Tom and Jerry are a unit" and not "Tom and Jerry is a unit" (sorry if this sentence doesn't make sense, I had to come up with something). The same goes for German. Still, I am not a native speaker so I may be wrong here.

Comment: *Eins*, *zwei Äpfel* or *ein Apfel* isn't an object. The copula *sein* (*werden*, *bleiben*, *heißen* etc.) has no object. It associates two things that are the same, hence both being put into nominative case. That "nominative object" is called *predicative* then. In general, predicatives may be anthing, even whole phrases.